# Обращение к элементу в векторе структур

Tags: c++

У меня есть структура Words

```
struct Words {
    std::string word;
    int         count;
};
```

И вектор таких структур
`std::vector<Words> v;`

```
while(ist >> tmp)
    {
        if(tmp.length() >= 3)
        {
            v.insert.word(v.end(), tmp);
        }
    }
```

Мне нужно в цикле заполнить поле word строкой tmp.
Но при обращении `v.insert.word(v.end(), tmp);`компилятор выдаёт ошибку.
Как мне правильно построить обращение к полю `v.word`?

Comment: У меня есть пустой вектор v типа words. Я хочу в цикле заполнить поле word вектора v строкой tmp. Как мне построить обращение к полю word вектора v?

Answer (score 1):

Еще раз и медленно :) - у вас уже есть готовый вектор `Words`, и вы хотите у имеющихся (не новодобавляемых) `Words` сделать поле `word` равным `tmp`?

Или - исходя из `insert` - вы хотите добавить?

Если добавить - то, например,

```
v.push_back({tmp,0});
```

(`0` здесь - значение `count` для добавляемого элемента `Words`)

Comment: У меня есть пустой вектор v типа words. Я хочу в цикле заполнить поле word вектора v строкой tmp. Как мне построить обращение к полю word вектора v?

Comment: Как я вам написал. `while(ist >> tmp)
    {
        if(tmp.length() >= 3)
        {
            v.push_back({tmp,0});
        }
    }`

Comment: @Abyx Тогда надо дописать конструктор `Words`.